# Can't get Plupload Integration test module to work

Tags: 9

I've installed **Plupload integration** on my Drupal 9 local Docksal site but can't get the example module to work.  The library is properly installed according to Status Report.  I enabled "Plupload test" went to the test page, tried to upload a zip file and the file won't upload.  In the console I see an error at **/plupload-handle-uploads?token=XJtEGstKW7...**

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":105,"message":"Invalid temporary file name."},"id":"id"}
```

I'm able to upload files just fine through the media manager so I don't think it's my local site configuration.  I don't have a self-signed SSL certificate working locally - could that be it?

Comment: It could be something like https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload/issues/2106583. What is the temporary directory configuration?

Comment: All other site operations that involve the temp. directory work, so I'm guessing that it probably isn't an issue.  I think I'm going to just make my feature work with a normal file upload field.  Drag and drop is a nicety in my use-case, not a requirement.  Thanks for the suggestion @cilefen